# How to read verbose VC++ linker output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Trying to debug some linker errors, I turned on /VERBOSE and I'm trying to make sense of the output. It occurs to me that I really don't know how to read it.

For example:

```
1>Compiling version info
1>Linking...
1>Starting pass 1
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:mfc80.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:mfcs80.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib
....
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libgslcblasMD.lib
1>Searching libraries
1>    Searching V:\Src\Solutions\\..\..\\Common\Win32\Lib\PlxApi.lib:
1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\camerageometry.lib:
1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\geometry.lib:
1>      Found "public: __thiscall VisionMap::Geometry::Box2d::operator class VisionMap::Geometry::Box2DInt(void)const " (??BBox2d@Geometry@VisionMap@@QBE?AVBox2DInt@12@XZ)
1>        Referenced in FocusDlg.obj
1>        Loaded geometry.lib(Box2d.obj)
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:CGAL-vc80-mt.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_33_1.lib
```

What's going on here?

I think I understand this bit:

```
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libgslcblasMD.lib
1>Searching libraries
1>    Searching V:\Src\Solutions\\..\..\\Common\Win32\Lib\PlxApi.lib:
1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\camerageometry.lib:
1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\geometry.lib:
1>      Found "public: __thiscall VisionMap::Geometry::Box2d::operator class VisionMap::Geometry::Box2DInt(void)const " (??BBox2d@Geometry@VisionMap@@QBE?AVBox2DInt@12@XZ)
1>        Referenced in FocusDlg.obj
1>        Loaded geometry.lib(Box2d.obj)
```

It's trying to find the implementation of the above operator, which is used somewhere in FocusDlg.cpp, and it finds it in geometry.lib.

But what does `1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libgslcblasMD.lib` mean? What determines the order of symbol resolution? Why is it loading this particular symbol while processing `libgslcblasMD.lib` which is a 3rd party library? Or am I reading it wrong?

It seems that the linker is going through the symbols referenced in the project's various object files, but I have no idea in what order. It then searches the static libraries the project uses - by project reference, explicit import and automatic default library imports; but it does so in an order that, again, seems arbitrary to me.

When it finds a symbol, for example in geometry.lib, it then continues to find a bunch of other symbols from the same lib:

```
1>    Searching V:\Src\Solutions\\..\..\\Common\Win32\Lib\PlxApi.lib:
1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\camerageometry.lib:
1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\geometry.lib:
1>      Found "public: __thiscall VisionMap::Geometry::Box2d::operator class VisionMap::Geometry::Box2DInt(void)const " (??BBox2d@Geometry@VisionMap@@QBE?AVBox2DInt@12@XZ)
1>        Referenced in FocusDlg.obj
1>        Loaded geometry.lib(Box2d.obj)
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:CGAL-vc80-mt.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_33_1.lib
1>      Found "public: __thiscall VisionMap::Geometry::Box2DInt::Box2DInt(int,int,int,int)" (??0Box2DInt@Geometry@VisionMap@@QAE@HHHH@Z)
1>        Referenced in FocusDlg.obj
1>        Referenced in ImageView.obj
1>        Referenced in geometry.lib(Box2d.obj)
1>        Loaded geometry.lib(Box2DInt.obj)
1>      Found "public: virtual __thiscall VisionMap::Geometry::Point3d::~Point3d(void)" (??1Point3d@Geometry@VisionMap@@UAE@XZ)
1>        Referenced in GPSFrm.obj
1>        Referenced in MainFrm.obj
1>        Loaded geometry.lib(Point3d.obj)
1>      Found "void __cdecl VisionMap::Geometry::serialize<class boost::archive::binary_oarchive>(class boost::archive::binary_oarchive &,class VisionMap::Geometry::Point3d &,unsigned int)" (??$serialize@Vbinary_oarchive@archive@boost@@@Geometry@VisionMap@@YAXAAVbinary_oarchive@archive@boost@@AAVPoint3d@01@I@Z)
1>        Referenced in GPSFrm.obj
1>        Referenced in MainFrm.obj
1>        Loaded geometry.lib(GeometrySerializationImpl.obj)
```

But then, for some reason, it goes on to find symbols that are defined in other libs, and returns to geometry later on (a bunch of times).

So clearly it's not doing "look in geometry and load every symbol that's references in the project, and then continue to other libraries". But it's not clear to me what *is* the order of symbol lookup.

And what's the deal with all those libraries being processed at the beginning of the linker's work, but not finding any symbols to load from them? Does this project really not use anything from `msvcrt.lib`, `kernel32.lib`? Seems unlikely.

So basically I'm looking to decipher the underlying order in the linker's operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search for symbols to link starts at your app entry point (main, or WinMain). From there the linker gets all the symbols to which the entry point depends, loads their own dependencies, and so on, until there are no dependencies left.

In older linkers, any .obj included in the main project would necessarily be linked, and so their dependencies should be present in the project for the link to succeed. Today, most linkers strip out code that's never used, even when it's contained in explicitly linked obj files.

About `1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libgslcblasMD.lib`: this simply means that the library file was scanned, and its symbols were appended to a dictionary to later use it for dependencies resolution.

The order in which the resolution occurs doesn't have necessarily any relation to the order in which library files are processed. When the linker processes a lib it simply adds its symbols to the dictionary. The dependencies resolution is made after that dictionary was populated, starting at the main entry point, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you ignored or could not paste the first 2 lines of the build log. They will be as follows:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: <ProjectName>, Configuration: (e.g. Debug x64) ------
```

I could decode the logs as follows:

1. The first few characters in each line (e.g. '1>') in the logs represents the project number. Treat them like project id and it means that the corresponding log is output while processing the respective project.
2. The project id ('1' in '1>...') is not necessarily single threaded. That is, the tasks are not executed synchronously. (This can also be seen in your output).
3. Two Tasks are being performed in parallel as also seen from the output in your example. They are:

> A. Processing libraries

> B. Searching libraries

4. The task, "Processing Libraries", appears containing the word "Processed" as in example:

> ```
>    1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:CGAL-vc80-mt.lib
> ```

5. The task, "Processing Libraries" might be doing some bookkeeping as also mentioned by @Fabio Ceconello
6. The task, "Searching Libraries", appears containing the word "Searching" as in example:

> ```
>   1>    Searching ..\..\..\..\out\win32\release\lib\geometry.lib:
> ```

7. The task, "Searching Libraries", contains further logs that are indented and hence signifies that something is happening with these libraries.
8. The task, "Searching Libraries", will search for all exported symbols in the library that is being used by the current project/module as explained in the excerpt below:

> ```
> 1>      Found "public: __thiscall VisionMap::Geometry::Box2d::operator class VisionMap::Geometry::Box2DInt(void)const " (??BBox2d@Geometry@VisionMap@@QBE?AVBox2DInt@12@XZ)
> 1>        Referenced in FocusDlg.obj
> 1>        Loaded geometry.lib(Box2d.obj)
> ```

This excerpt says that Project ('1>') is using the symbol 'VisionMap::Geometry::Box2D::operator' in file/class 'FocusDlg' (belonging to project '1>'). This function "Box2D::operator" is defined in the file/class "Box2D" in module(another project) "geometry". This project "geometry" is being/should be linked to the current project ('1>').

9. The task "Searching Libraries" first fully processed on a given library (e.g. geometry.lib) before moving to the next library. This task will run on multiple libraries synchronously. Look at this task independently from other tasks.
10. The task "Searching Libraries" will search the libraries in the order defined in your project configurations: "Input -> Additional Dependencies" and "Input -> Additonal Library Directories".
    You can verify this against the build log.
    This might not be the only criteria.

Other information if left out or confusing can be taken up as Q&A.