# Profiling visual c++ link time

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to reduce the link-time of my project, and to do that I want to understand, exactly, why it takes so long - is it a specific library? is it something else? How can I know what to change in order to improve the link time?

**Update**

There are many "generic" advices such as "reduce library dependencies" but they seem impractical in our case. Our code-base is large, there are many library dependencies, and finding out, *by experimenting*, which dependency affects the link time the most will take an enormous amount of time. A large portion of the code base was developed years ago without thinking that much about dependencies. We are looking for a way to find a concrete direction, such as "dependency of X on Y will benefit the link time", **without** exhaustively trying all possible directions..

Note that we are not using LTCG at all.

Comment: There's some good advice [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/10/30/the-visual-c-linker-best-practices-developer-iteration.aspx) and similar previously asked questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143808/how-to-improve-link-performance-for-a-large-c-application-in-vs2005/9733242#9733242) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921693/how-to-speed-up-c-linking-time).

Comment: See update. I wrote more specifically what I am looking for.

Comment: You could start assess your link operation by enabling the verbose level log output linker option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850620/how-to-read-verbose-vc-linker-output

Comment: The only thing I am missing is a way to print the time of each log entry.. so I can understand which operations take a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I modified the project properties for my executable that takes a long time to link and added `/VERBOSE` to the linker command line. That way, the linker produces a detailed log of what it is doing.

Then, I wrote a small powershell script to timestamp each line that my build produces. That way I can see how much time passes between the lines the linker prints. Assuming the linker is not lying about what it is doing, this gives me quite a good hint about how much time it spends doing which operation.

Here is the powershell code:

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=X64 /m MY_SOLUTION.sln *>&1 | & {
    process {
        $date = get-date -DisplayHint Time -Format hh:mm:ss.fff
        Write-Host $date -NoNewLine
        Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Visual C++, I think the first step in the linking time optimization is to turn off the 'Whole-Program Optimization (/GL)' option.

I would like to recommend a book on this subject: [Large-Scale C++ Software Design, by John Lakos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620). This book gives many good points on the large scale C++ development, but I think the main theme is 'how to design package relationship to minimize linking time'.

It is about module(lib, dll) dependency minimization techniques. Because, linking a project consists of many small modules is tend to run faster than one big (many files) project.

Also, check out this blog post: [The “Large-Scale C++ Software Design” rules in practice](http://blog.codeimproved.net/2009/03/the-large-scale-c-software-design-rules-in-practice/)